# Discrepancy in data values while opening .csv file manually and by using python query

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Data Source**: https://www.kaggle.com/worldbank/world-development-indicators
**Folder**: 'world-development-indicators'

When I **manually check the database** by opening the csv file in MS-Excel, I find the **number of years** to be from **1960 to 1980** (min year 1960 and max year 1980).

However when I **run** the below command in **python**, I get the **total number of years** to be **1960 to 2015**. And the max year to be 2015 (min year continues to be 1960)

```
data = pd.read_csv('./world-development-indicators/Indicators.csv')
years = data['Year'].unique().tolist()
len(years)

o/p: 56 

 years.min
 o/p: 1960

 years.max
 o/p: 2015
```

If the maximum year in .csv file when opened manually is 1980, then why am I getting the maximum value of Year column as 2015 while executing python query.

Has anyone faced such an issue? Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file you have mentioned contains 5.65 million records. I have tested this in MS-Excel as well as Libre Office on Linux, it gives me an error message that not all rows can been loaded. Hence, you see records only until 1980.

I did a:

```
data.describe()
```

And found the `min` and `max` to be 1960 and 2015. Also, the year is increasing in the file. If you do a `data.head(5)` and `data.tail(5)`, you will notice the following:

```
data.tail(5)
Out[109]: 
        CountryName CountryCode  ...  Year  Value
5656453    Zimbabwe         ZWE  ...  2015   36.0
5656454    Zimbabwe         ZWE  ...  2015   90.0
5656455    Zimbabwe         ZWE  ...  2015  242.0
5656456    Zimbabwe         ZWE  ...  2015    3.3
5656457    Zimbabwe         ZWE  ...  2015   32.8

[5 rows x 6 columns]

data.head(5)
Out[110]: 
  CountryName CountryCode  ...  Year         Value
0  Arab World         ARB  ...  1960  1.335609e+02
1  Arab World         ARB  ...  1960  8.779760e+01
2  Arab World         ARB  ...  1960  6.634579e+00
3  Arab World         ARB  ...  1960  8.102333e+01
4  Arab World         ARB  ...  1960  3.000000e+06
```

---

PS: If you use Spyder, you can open the `Variable Explorer` section, double click on `data`, and you should see all the records. I prefer this over opening in Excel because Excel usually truncates the records at the bottom if the file is large.